# Copy constructor not getting called at function return

Tags: c++, c++11

Sorry for the long description, but I'm not sure how can I explain this problem I am facing in short.

I'm having following class from the book C++ Primer Lippman et. at.

```
// Sales_data.h

class Sales_data {
    friend Sales_data add(const Sales_data&, const Sales_data&);
    friend std::ostream &print(std::ostream&, const Sales_data&);
    friend std::istream &read(std::istream&, Sales_data&);
    friend std::ostream &operator<<(std::ostream&, const Sales_data&);
    friend std::istream &operator>>(std::istream&, Sales_data&);
public:
    // constructors
    Sales_data(); //  = default;
    Sales_data(const std::string &);
    Sales_data(const Sales_data &);
    Sales_data(const std::string &, unsigned, double);
    Sales_data(std::istream &);

    // destructor
    ~Sales_data();

    // operations on Sales_data objects
    std::string isbn() const { return bookNo; }
    Sales_data& combine(const Sales_data&);
    double avg_price() const;
private:
    std::string bookNo;
    unsigned units_sold = 0;
    double revenue = 0.0;
};
```

And following are the implementation of default constructor, Copy constructor and destructor with logging
to enable debugging.

```
// Sales_data.cpp

Sales_data::Sales_data() {
    std::cout << "<" << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << ">:" << this << std::endl;
}

Sales_data::Sales_data(const Sales_data &rhs) {
    std::cout << "<Copy Constructor:" << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__
        << ">:From:" << &rhs << ",To:" << this << std::endl;
    bookNo = rhs.bookNo;
    units_sold = rhs.units_sold;
    revenue = rhs.revenue;
}

Sales_data::~Sales_data() {
    std::cout << "<" << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << ">:" << this << std::endl;
}
```

Driver program for this is :

```
/// test.cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

#include "Sales_data.h"

using namespace std;


Sales_data global;

Sales_data foo_bar(Sales_data arg) {
    Sales_data local = arg, *heap = new Sales_data(global);
    cout << "Before *heap = local; ..." << endl;
    *heap = local;
    cout << "Initializing array pa[4] ..." << endl;
    Sales_data pa[4] = {local, *heap};
    cout << "Done initializing array pa[4] ..." << endl;
    return *heap;

}


int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    //v.emplace_back("978-0590353403", 25, 15.99);
    //v.emplace_back("978-0590353404", 25, 15.99);

    Sales_data sd, ret;

    cout << "Now calling foo_bar() ..." << endl;
    ret = foo_bar(sd);
    cout << "Addr =" << &ret << endl;
    cout << "Returned from foo_bar() ..." << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Below is the output.

```
onkar@titan:~/cpp$ ./test
<Sales_data::Sales_data()>:0x55e200b2a160
<Sales_data::Sales_data()>:0x7ffc4f355840
<Sales_data::Sales_data()>:0x7ffc4f355870
Now calling foo_bar() ...
<Copy Constructor:Sales_data::Sales_data(const Sales_data&)>:From:0x7ffc4f355840,To:0x7ffc4f3558a0
<Copy Constructor:Sales_data::Sales_data(const Sales_data&)>:From:0x7ffc4f3558a0,To:0x7ffc4f355700
<Copy Constructor:Sales_data::Sales_data(const Sales_data&)>:From:0x55e200b2a160,To:0x55e20180e2c0  << *heap = new Sales_data(global);
Before *heap = local; ...
Initializing array pa[4] ...
<Copy Constructor:Sales_data::Sales_data(const Sales_data&)>:From:0x7ffc4f355700,To:0x7ffc4f355730  << pa[0] = local
<Copy Constructor:Sales_data::Sales_data(const Sales_data&)>:From:0x55e20180e2c0,To:0x7ffc4f355760  << pa[1] = *heap
<Sales_data::Sales_data()>:0x7ffc4f355790
<Sales_data::Sales_data()>:0x7ffc4f3557c0
Done initializing array pa[4] ...
<Copy Constructor:Sales_data::Sales_data(const Sales_data&)>:From:0x55e20180e2c0,To:0x7ffc4f3558d0 << This point ****
<Sales_data::~Sales_data()>:0x7ffc4f3557c0
<Sales_data::~Sales_data()>:0x7ffc4f355790
<Sales_data::~Sales_data()>:0x7ffc4f355760
<Sales_data::~Sales_data()>:0x7ffc4f355730
<Sales_data::~Sales_data()>:0x7ffc4f355700
<Sales_data::~Sales_data()>:0x7ffc4f3558d0
<Sales_data::~Sales_data()>:0x7ffc4f3558a0
Addr =0x7ffc4f355870
Returned from foo_bar() ...
<Sales_data::~Sales_data()>:0x7ffc4f355870
<Sales_data::~Sales_data()>:0x7ffc4f355840
<Sales_data::~Sales_data()>:0x55e200b2a160
onkar@titan:~/cpp$
```

In this output, I was expecting copy constructor being called (to copy *heap to ret) when the function foo_bar returns, but this is not happening.

Please help me understand why copy constructor is not getting called.

Comment: [OT]: `heap = new Sales_data(global)`. never deleted -> memory leak.

Comment: @Jarod42 Yes I know, but that's how it is in the book, but that's not a point of the question. But anyways good find. Thanks.  BTW, this is question from the book (Exercise 13.1.1)

Comment: The compiler is allowed to elide certain copy operations (even if the copy constructor has side effects): https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Copy_elision

Comment: @chtz Tried g++ -fno-elide-constructors to disable Copy elision, but still the same output.

Comment: In the output, there's `<Copy Constructor:Sales_data` line right after `Done initializing array pa[4] ...` line. Is this not the copy constructor you are looking for?

Comment: @IgorTandetnik I don't think so, because From:0x55e20180e2c0,To:0x7ffc4f3558d0, but  To address should be Addr =0x7ffc4f355870, moreover this is not the copy constructor because destructors for variables on the function foo_bar are called after that.. Shouldn't happen after these destructors ?

Comment: No, it shouldn't happen after the destructors. If say the return value is copied from a local variable, of course that local variable has to be destroyed **after** it's been copied from. So local variables are necessarily destroyed after the return value is prepared.

Comment: `ret = foo_bar(sd);` doesn't copy into `ret` - it assigns to `ret`. A temporary object (let's call it `temp`) is copy-constructed from `*heap` in `foo_bar`, then `ret.operator=(temp)` is called in `main`.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik Okay ! but how about the address of return ? Shouldn't  To: address in Copy constructor log line you indicated be addr of ret variable in main that I am printing ? Thanks,

Comment: No, because you don't copy-construct `ret`. `ret` is default-constructed a few lines above.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik After changing Sales_data ret = foo_bar(sd);, it's now working as expected. To Address in Copy Constructor is addr of ret. That works ! Thanks.